# imitate on-tap at angular element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm excuse for possible repeat question, but I didn't find solution for my problem.

There is a simulation of button click when controller is loading. It worked good until I changed `ng-click` to `on-tap` (ionic application). Now it doesn't work at all. How can I imitate click for `on-tap`?

Previous version of imitate:

```
        var triggeredButton = document.getElementById('some_id');
        angular.element(triggeredButton).triggerHandler('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.element(triggeredButton).triggerHandler('mousedown');
```

or

```
angular.element(triggeredButton).triggerHandler('touchstart mousedown');
```

Comment: this is phonegap application and those methods won't work. P.S. Just in case I tried and both aren't work